# Pandas add or subtract a datetime object to obtain a shifted date using DateOffset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe:

```
    data hour
2015-01-02 1
2015-01-02 2
```

I'd subtract one day when hour = 2. So I use:

```
df.loc[(df['hour'] = 2), 'date'] = df['date'] - DateOffset(days=1)
```

I'm expecting something like

```
    data hour
2015-01-02 1
2015-01-01 2
```

Instead it returns:

```
    data hour
2015-01-02 1
1388620800000000000 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next version (0.17.0) of `pandas`.  I think in 0.16.2 it will raise, so I'm guessing you may be on an older version?

As a workaround for now you can could do this.

```
In [16]: df.loc[(df['hour'] == 2), 'data'] = df['data'] - pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: it returns this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'Timedelta'

Comment: Yes Pandas 0.16.2 return the same error using DateOffset